# Cucumber jvm seems to use System.exit

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm

I am calling Cucumber JVM as part of a maven life cycle using the exec plugin.  However, Cucumber seems to use System.exit() when it terminates so it prematurely stops my maven run.  This forces me to fork it to a separate process but that presents issues when I am trying to debug a test.

Is there a way to politely ask Cucumber JVM to not use System.exit() when it terminates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm assuming there is a good reason not to use the junit runner & that you're calling `cucumber.api.cli.Main`, if either assumption is false pls clarify the question)

The simplest/most expedient solution, given that `cucumber.api.cli.Main` is approx 4 lines of code, is to write your own main method that is a clone of the cucumber one without the `System.exit` call.

Separately you could raise the issue on their github site and/or send them a pull request with the required tweak to their `Main` class (e.g. don't do the system.exit if some system property has been set).

Comment: That's a great idea Matt.  Will look into it, thanks. Yes I'm using cucumber.api.cli.Main and I have a good reason for not using the junit runner.

Answer (score 1):

when calling commandline, use

```
mvn exec:exec
```

instead of

```
mvn exec:java
```

to avoid that maven is run in the same VM as cucumber.
[exex:exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html)
[exec:java](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)

Comment: I tried that but it does not solve my debugging problem.  Once I exec:exec, the IDE looses its handle on whatever I execute.